# Twitter API v1.1 - Posting a Tweet fails only when `status` includes a URL

Tags: twitter

I've used the Twitter API a number of times in the past, and am familiar with the authentication flow. I'm implementing a Twitter bot with a Dart-based client I created myself ([link](https://github.com/thosakwe/twit)), and everything works well, from GET's to POST's to streaming API requests.

However, I am struggling with posting Tweets with URL's in them. Using the `/statuses/update.json` endpoint, I can successfully post a Tweet with just plaintext, such as:

`@thosakwe Hello, world!`

However, once I add a link to the `status` parameter, I get a `Could not authenticate you.` error. I suspected that I might need to URL-encode the link in my status, but I still get the same error.

Does anyone know what's wrong here? Thanks in advance.

EDIT: Here's my code. You might not be familiar with `Dart`, but this is essentially just a port of the NPM `twit` library.

```
const String ANNOUNCE_BETA =
'https://medium.com/the-angel-framework/announcing-angel-v1-0-0-beta-46dfb4aa8afe';

const List<String> STATUSES = const [
  '@<handle> A #dartlang fan like you should take a look at the Angel server framework! $ANNOUNCE_BETA',
  '@<handle> Angel, a #dartlang server framework, is now in beta. Take it for a spin? $ANNOUNCE_BETA',
  '@<handle> Angel is a rising full-stack server framework for #dartlang. Check it out! $ANNOUNCE_BETA',
  '@<handle> You can take your #dartlang skills onto the server, too! Check out Angel! $ANNOUNCE_BETA',
  '@<handle> Have you tried Angel, a full-stack #dartlang server framework? Now in beta! $ANNOUNCE_BETA'
];

final RegExp _link = new RegExp(
r'https?:\/\/(www\.)?[-a-zA-Z0-9@:%._\+~#=]{2,256}\.[a-z]{2,4}\b([-a-zA-Z0-9@:%_\+.~#?&//=]*)');

String chooseStatus(Random rnd, String handle) {
  return STATUSES[rnd.nextInt(STATUSES.length)]
      .replaceAll('<handle>', handle)
      .replaceAllMapped(_link, (m) => Uri.encodeComponent(m[0]));
}

Future handleTimeline(Twit twit, Map tweet, String myHandle, Random rnd) async {
  Map user = tweet['user'];
  String tweetId = tweet['id_str'],
      text = tweet['text'],
      handle = user['screen_name'];

  if (handle != myHandle) {
    print("Responding to tweet from @$handle: '$text'");
    var status = chooseStatus(rnd, handle);
    await twit.post('/statuses/update.json',
    {'status': status, 'in_reply_to_status_id': tweetId});
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you show us the code that you're using?

Comment: @TerenceEden Just added it. Some things might look like blank strings here, but they are the string `'<handle>'`, and SO has stripped it out.